# default search provider corrupted in IE when running as another user

Tags: internet-explorer, active-directory, watin

I am using Watin to do some automated testing and I am running IE as a different user then attaching to the IE instance.  The problem is with Internet Explorer.  I get a message saying that the default search provider is corrupted.  I have reproduced this on two computers.  Is there a way of getting around this?  Can turn the warnings off somehow?  Or is there some kind of registry hack for turning it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a documented mechanism for turning off the prompt, because that would defeat the purpose (allowing evil software to disable the prompt and change the provider without permission).

Have you tried logging in as the user in question, correcting the provider, and then logging back out before retrying?

Comment: Yes, I logged out of windows with my user.  Logged in with the target user credentials, ran IE and I don't get the error in there.  I have noticed a difference between when I'm logged in as and when I run as.  When I'm logged in as the target user, the default search provider is bing.  When I run as the target user, the default search provider is Live Search.  Could this be causing my problem?  If so, how do I reconcile the difference?

Comment: I have made the search providers the same for all my users and the hklm by through the following registry key
****\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes 
I did this for all my users and in the HKLM.  I have gotten it to work, but only when my target user is logged in.

I have using remote desktop, and I am logged in under my user and the target user at the same time.  If I log out with my target user, I get the same error again.  Is there a reason the user needs to be logged in for it to work without throuing this message?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the LoadUserProfile property of ProcessStartInfo to true

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
```